# Generate a list of existing functions across multiple files in C

Tags: c, shell, scripting, code-analysis

Due to paperwork that has to be filled out, I need to know how many functions exist in an entire C project.

The project is split across multiple folders, so ideally what I am looking for is something where you can type in:

```
FindAllTheFunctions --recursive /path/to/folder
```

And the result is written something like:

```
/path.../filename: int foo(float bar)
.
.
.
/path.../final/filename: double foo2(int bar2)
```

How could I get results of this nature?

Many thanks!

Comment: I can only imagine the sheer idiocy of this kind of paperwork... Still, for C you may get a good approximation of what you are asking parsing the output of ctags.

Comment: The [`grep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/egrep.1.html) command comes to mind.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: even just for C writing a regex to match moderately complex function declarations is a horrible mess.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I know right? But paperwork is a part of my job so I don't mind. I just tried using ctags (for the first time) using: `ctags --recurse=yes *`. It created a mess of a file and I couldn't see any immediate pattern in the output that would indicate whether something was a function or not?

Comment: @MatteoItalia I know! ;) Actually, it's *impossible* to write a regex to match all possible function declarations, since there may be nested parentheses, which regexes really can't handle. It's just a way to get the OP to search a little more, since this question is off-topic here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How is this question about code analysis off-topic? Also I searched first, naturally, but didn't find anything satisfactory yet.

Comment: It sounds like you need `cproto` which will scan C-source files creating a concise list of the function declaration. You can collected the declarations from all files in your project. It does a wonderful job. [**http://invisible-island.net/cproto/cproto.html**](http://invisible-island.net/cproto/cproto.html). Give it a look.

Comment: The off-topic part is that you ask for links to off-site resource or tools. From the section ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help): "Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resourc*e are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @Nextor: look for lines with an `f` in the last field; those are functions; the first field is the function name, the rest isn't interesting for you. Counting these lines will give you the number of function definitions in your project.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah, thank you! I'll write better questions in the future, and edit this one a little bit now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: and I know that you know, that's why I didn't understand why you suggested such a terrible solution ; still, it was important to point out that regexes are the wrong way, last time I had to convince someone of the impossibility of matching C declarations with regexes it took a while and wasn't fun (I had to revise function pointers and array pointers syntax). 

Comment: @MatteoItalia Like "they" say: You have a problem. You solve it with regular expressions. Now you have *two* problems. :)

Comment: @Neztor While using `grep` might not be the best tool for extracting function declarations (for simple declarations it's certainly works though) once you have the output from `ctags` or `cproto` you can use `grep` to extract the information you want. For example using the file generated by `ctags` you can `grep` for the trailing `f` and use [`wc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html) to count the number of lines, which should correspond to the number of functions.

Comment: Would a linker map file not list all the functions?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit No idea, but it sounds interesting, would you like to elaborate on it?

Comment: @Neztor not really into reading docs for others..  Look at your own linker documentation.  There may well be some command-line, or other, parameter that instructs the linker to generate a comprehensive map file that includes a list of all functions, (and probably their address, length etc).  IME, the info on each function is on one line, so it would be easy to count the lines.   It's a suggestion - it may work on your linker, may not.. :)

Comment: It's also likely that a full debug build would contain what you need in the debug info appended to the executable.  This info could also be extracted/listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving/expanding from the comments, a slightly more general one-liner:

```
ctags -f - -R | cut -s -f 4- | grep -P '(^|\t)f($|\t)' | wc -l
```

1. `ctags -R` parses (... mostly...) recursively the supported files in the current directory; `-f -` redirects its output to stdout instead of writing a `tags` file;
2. we use `cut` to only extract the fields we are interested in;

   The `tags` file format is made of fields separated by tabs (so the default delimiters for `cut` are already ok); the first three fields have a fixed meaning and are not of our interest, while the ones that follow are "extended fields", where we are looking for a single `f` that indicates that the row refers to a function.

   `-s` matches only lines with delimiters (= skip garbage); `-f 4-` outputs only from the fourth field to the last.
3. we use `grep` to look for our lonely `f`; the order of "extended fields" is not guaranteed - and in facts, when calling `ctags` over a C++ project I saw that extra fields besides `f` are added (`class:` fields in particular).

   `-P` uses PCRE regexes (just because it's easier to look for a tab character, `egrep` would suffice otherwise); `(^|\t)f($|\t)` looks for an `f` either surrounded by our separators (tabs) or by the start/end of line;
4. `wc -l` counts the resulting lines; the result should be the number of function definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for all of your useful comments!

In the end, this is what I did:
I created the `tags` file using `ctags`:

```
ctags --recurse=yes path/to/base/of/code
```

This generates an output file called `tags`

I use `vim` as a text editor. So I opened the `tags` file and typed:

```
:v/f$/d
```

Which searches for all lines in the file that don't end with `f` and deletes them.

What I was left with were all of the functions from the code. How many functions?

```
wc -l tags
```

It is only 535 functions, now I have to document them all...

Answer (score 0):

The cross reference feature of ctags may help you.

1. Install Universal-ctags (https://ctags.io)
2. Run find $dir --name '*.c' | ctags --kinds-C=f -x --_xformat='%F: %{C.properties} %t %N%S'

> ```
> $ find ./main -name '*.c' | ./ctags --kinds-C=f -x --_xformat='%F: %{C.properties} %t %N%S' -L - | head
> ./main/args.c: extern Arguments * argNewFromArgv(char * const * const argv)
> ./main/args.c: extern Arguments * argNewFromFile(FILE * const fp)
> ./main/args.c: extern Arguments * argNewFromLineFile(FILE * const fp)
> ./main/args.c: extern Arguments * argNewFromString(const char * const string)
> ./main/args.c: extern bool argOff(const Arguments * const current)
> ./main/args.c: extern char * argItem(const Arguments * const current)
> ./main/args.c: extern void argDelete(Arguments * const current)
> ./main/args.c: extern void argForth(Arguments * const current)
> ./main/args.c: extern void argSetLineMode(Arguments * const current)
> ./main/args.c: extern void argSetWordMode(Arguments * const current)
> ```